# Overflow property on TD elements in an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using HTML tables to show my data in tabular form. I know that the

> Default behavior of `td` elements in a table is that they change their width and height in order to accommodate the text inside it i.e. like that shown in figure (A)

[image]

Is it possible that I some how achieve the effect as shown in `figure (b)` , i.e. I would like to modify the `td` elements using CSS in such a way that it gets the shape as that in `Figure (b)` i.e. maintain it's width and height but makes the text inside itself overlay the sibling `td` elements?

[image]

PS: Have tried fixing the width and height plus using the `overflow` property of CSS but that didn't work.

**NOTE** 
I don't want to use the `colspan` property, i.e. I still want the sibling `td` to be there (of course, they won't have any content inside them).

The reason **Why** I want to achieve this is I'm using [jQuery plugin Datatable](http://datatables.net/index) and this doesn't work with the table having `td`s that are using `colspan` property

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything like that but you can investigate the `wrap` and `whitespace` CSS properties and maybe make some headway.

Comment: It would be better if you make a fiddle from your code, to try on.

Comment: @KamranAhmed I guess the only change is to add an absolutely positioned extra element into `td`.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the idea, but please let me wait, if anyone might be able to suggest something else!

Comment: If you want to achieve the effect as shown in figure (B), `colspan` is exactly what you have to use. That's what tables can do, that's what they are designed for. If some third party lib hinders you with that, lose the third party lib. That is all. I'm not even going to suggest you might find `<caption>` useful, because with a stupid lib like that, it will probably barf at captions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, using @teemu suggestion, i.e.

> Using an absolutely positioned extra element into `td`